# apache to lighttpd mod_rewrite on codeigniter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

Im on codeigniter now but im having a little problem when i change my server from Apache to Lighttpd.

I use this snippet for my .htacces

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Please help me on how to convert this into lighttp mod_rewrite. Cheers!